# Recreate model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working on a rails app for a while now and want to recreate the model without going through all the migration stages (i.e. from scratch) now that I finally have a final design for how I want it to be built.

How do I do this without having to have to recreate my entire project?

Comment: What do you mean by recreating the model? You want to change some attributes or want to change model name ?

Comment: I have several tables which has gone through many changes to get to where it is today. I want to sort of start from the beginning with my current design.

Comment: Rails has a migration system that takes care of all your database changes. Sorry maybe I'm not getting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly about what you want,

```
rake db:reset
```

will recreate your database from your db/schema.rb. Make sure that you have run all the migrations before running it.

However, rails manage the database using the migration files in db/migrate. Everytime you make changes to the database you will need to do it through them or you will get into trouble. These files should be retained and whenever you deloy your app to a new machine, running db:migrate should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could delete all your migration files and copy everything from db/schema.rb to a new migration.